# Как создать список пар, соответственных элементов двух двумерных списков? Python

Tags: python, массивы, list

У меня два двумерных списка

```
a = [[1, -1],
     [-2, 4]]

b = [['!', '+'],
     ['&', 'x']]
```

Я хочу получить список пар соответственных значений, т.е.

```
result = [(1, '!'), (-1, '+'), (-2, '&'), (4, 'x')]
```

Знаю как сделать через вложенные списки или через zip, а затем перебор. Есть ли более релевантный способ?

Comment: Так пара вложенных циклов же, если zip не нравится. Что значит "более релевантный"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам нужна короткая запись, то

```
result = list(zip(sum(a, []), sum(b, [])))
```

даст вам требуемый список кортежей.

Answer (score 1):

```py
result = [x for xs in map(zip, a, b) for x in xs]
```